# Revive adserver: how to add extra field at add new advertiser section

Tags: php, mysql, openx, advertisement-server

i am new to  revive adserver and i need to add an extra field at '**Add new advertiser**' section.please help me to achieve this...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just change advertiser-edit.php file in www/admin folder. So, you can add any type of data and make insert and get from database. Also, you need to change language files

default.lang.php

add fields like below :

$GLOBALS['strAddress']                          = "Address";

Comment: How did you know that this file has to be edited? Revive Adserver's documentation is not very helpful either. If you could please share a source or any resource about this adserver at your disposal , that would be great . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to add fields in the 
advertiser-edit.php in `\www\admin` folder. Later to store in the database , you need to add attributes in db_schema.ini file in `\lib\max\Dal\DataObjects` folder.

This is also applicable to rest of the edit pages.